# I have a several variants and need to merge in a manifest file for deep links

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have project directory of src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, then I have src/variant1/AndroidManifest.xml and I can not figure out how the build file should be setup to merge the manifests. I am trying to deep link specifically for one variant and none of the others so I can't just stick it in the main manifest file. Documents like this http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html aren't exactly what I am looking for as no one really talks about manifests. I would ideally like to have it as the following with just adding my variant specific code to the manifest for the variant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<application>
    <activity
        android:name="company.ui.activities.SplashActivity_">
<intent-filter android:label="@string/brand_page_title_header">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="schemename"
                android:pathPrefix="/path" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```